# GORM: Is it possible to get a map of domain objects when executing a findAll()?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Say I have a simple domain class like the follow:

```
Class User {
    Long id
    Long clientId
    String firstName
    String lastName
}
```

If I do `User.FindAllByClientId(1)`, is it possible to get a map (with the id being the key) as follows?:

```
{
    235235: {
        id: 235235,
        clientId: 1,
        firstName: test,
        lastName: test
    },
    5326532: {
        id: 5326532,
        clientId: 1,
        firstName: test2,
        lastName: test2
    }
}
```

Currently, if I do a `findAll()`, I'll get a list. And I know I can loop over that list and construct the json on my own. I was just wondering whether there was a built-in functionality by grails, so that I don't have to go through the list right after making a DB call.

I don't necessarily need this done through GORM, I'm okay with criterias as well.

Comment: The short answer: No, `findAll()` always returns a `List`. You'll need to construct the `Map` yourself.

Comment: Is this not possible through criterias either?

Comment: No, criteria would also return a `List` as well. You'll have to make a `Map` yourself. Nothing in Grails will do this for you.